# C# Help to shorten this lenght of code that follows a obvious pattern

Tags: optimization

So i have this lenght of code with a Switch statement and 10 different cases. I want to shorten this code and i think it is possible because there is a obvious pattern between the cases which is the plus 10 - 90. Thanks.

this is text to make my post be able to publicize.
**So i have this lenght of code with a Switch statement and 10 different cases. I want to shorten this code and i think it is possible because there is a obvious pattern between the cases which is the plus 10 - 90. Thanks.
So i have this lenght of code with a Switch statement and 10 different cases. I want to shorten this code and i think it is possible because there is a obvious pattern between the cases which is the plus 10 - 90. Thanks.
So i have this lenght of code with a Switch statement and 10 different cases. I want to shorten this code and i think it is possible because there is a obvious pattern between the cases which is the plus 10 - 90. Thanks.
So i have this lenght of code with a Switch statement and 10 different cases. I want to shorten this code and i think it is possible because there is a obvious pattern between the cases which is the plus 10 - 90. Thanks.**

```
switch (Universe)
        {
            case 1:
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    EnemyNameButtonText[i].text = Enemy[i].Name;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    EnemyNameButtonText[i].text = Enemy[i + 10].Name;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    EnemyNameButtonText[i].text = Enemy[i + 20].Name;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    EnemyNameButtonText[i].text = Enemy[i + 30].Name;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    EnemyNameButtonText[i].text = Enemy[i + 40].Name;
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    EnemyNameButtonText[i].text = Enemy[i + 50].Name;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    EnemyNameButtonText[i].text = Enemy[i + 60].Name;
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    EnemyNameButtonText[i].text = Enemy[i + 70].Name;
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    EnemyNameButtonText[i].text = Enemy[i + 80].Name;
                }
                break;
            case 10:
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    EnemyNameButtonText[i].text = Enemy[i + 90].Name;
                }
                break;
        }
´´´ 

This would be a very good practice for me as a programmer. I have tried to search but it was to no awail so thank you if do decide to help me.
```

Comment: Think how you’d get 10 from 2, 20 from 3 etc with simple math. Then implement that

Comment: Oh okay, i understand so i should use the int i to my advantage